# What is the probability that you switch jobs in the next three years?

Tags: probability

On average, people switched jobs every three years. Suppose you have held your current job for two years. What is the probability that you switch jobs in the next three years?

**My Attempt**

We will model this using an exponential distribution. We are given $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}=3$, so $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$. Then the p.d.f. is
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{3}e^{-\frac{1}{3}x}$$
Integrate to get
$$F(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{3}}$$
So
$$\mathbb{P}(X=3)=1-e^{-\frac{3}{3}}=0.6321$$

Can someone verify this? I'm not sure where to use the information that I have already held my current job for three years. Or does that not matter?

Comment: The fact that you have currently held your job for two years shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume an exponential distribution then indeed $\mathbb P(X \le 3) \approx 0.6321$, though you wrote $\mathbb P(X = 3)$

You would get the same figure no matter how long you have been doing your current job, because exponential distributions are memoryless.

This assumption is critical: if instead you assumed everybody did one job for exactly $3$ years and then moved then that probability would become $1$.  Other assumptions, such as people either moving quickly because they do not fit in some new jobs or staying a long time because they do fit, would push the probability down.